# How to check for a substring in a Hashmap values

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a `HashMap<String, String>`.

```
map= {john=a024600000372TPAAY, Jam=Jam is not recognized, Dave=a024600000A1ndhAAB}
```

I want to find if my hashmap has any value which has a substring of "not recognized".

when I tried `map.containsValue("not recognized")` it returned a false, as it's looking for a value "not recognized", but I should find a way to check for a substring.

```
map.containsValue("not recognized")
```

Comment: Kinda defeats the purpose of Map.

Answer (score 5):

There's no good way to do it apart from iterating over all the values. 
Shortest way is probably using streams

```
map.values().stream()
            .filter(e -> e.contains("not recognized"))
            .findFirst()
            .orElse(null);
```

This will return the value if it matches or null if it doesn't.

Comment: You may want to include a default value since if "not recognized" isn't present, your method throws an exception.  Instead of `get()`, something using `orElse()`.

Answer (score 1):

`map.containsValue` looks for exact value in the all the values available in the map so you should use something like following:

```
boolean contains = false;
for (String value : map.values()) {
    if(value.contains("not recognized")){
        contains = true;
        break;
    }
}
if(contains){
    System.err.println("Map contains value");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in function for that.

You have to write your own code for that iterates the map (values), and then does whatever checking you need. With Java8, something like:

```
yourMap.values().stream().filter(v -> v.contains("not recognized")).count();
```

for example.

And note: if you are talking about really large maps, and a lot of data, then you should consider to use a more appropriate data structure. Maps are intended to quick access via **keys**, not via properties of the map values. If such "text searching" is your primary requirement, a "full text search engine", like [lucene](https://lucene.apache.org/core/).

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```java
      Map<String, String> map = Map.of("john",
            "a024600000372TPAAY",
            "Jam",
            "Jam is not recognized",
            "Dave",
            "a024600000A1ndhAAB");
      for (String key : map.keySet()) {
         if (map.containsValue(key + " is not recognized")) {
            System.out.println(key + " -> " + map.get(key));
         }
      }
```

I took your map example literally.  If you want to get the key for the first item that has "not recognized" you could do this.

```java
      String key = map.entrySet().stream().filter(
            e -> e.getValue().contains("not recognized")).map(
                  e -> e.getKey()).findFirst().orElse("All are recognized");
      System.out.println(key);
```

Comment: Your code is based on the assumption that the value says "KEY + not recognized" . That requirement isn't stated in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Question already has a few answers. I believe as OP more concern about if the `Map` values contain the string "not recognized" or not which means the `boolean` value will be enough. In that case, I think the below solution will be more optimized.

```
map.values()
    .stream()
    .anyMatch(e -> e.contains("not recognized"));
```